# How to fix parsing error: Unexpected Token ;?

Tags: php, html, web, velo

I'm trying to set up a filter for my Wix website. I was following this code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhMKnm1f6EU

But For some reason, I get an Error at the bottom.

```
    .contains("bedrooms", $w('#dropdown6').value
    .ge("bathrooms", $w('#dropdown5').value
    .between("price",paraFloat($w('#dropdown3').value), parseFloat($w('#dropdown4').value)))

.then((results) => {
        console.log("Dataset is now Filtered");
        $w("#repeater1").data = results.items;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
--> });                            
$w("#repeater1").expand();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its basically a syntax error. Its hard to say exactly what its from without seeing the rest of the code, but it appears to be that you're missing two closing parenthesis based on the code snippet you've posted. See the example below.

```
    .contains("bedrooms", $w('#dropdown6').value)
    .ge("bathrooms", $w('#dropdown5').value)
```

Note the parens at the end of each of those two lines that is missing from your code snippet. If you just add those in it should work (assuming you don't have any other syntax errors).